# How do I check if an element exists inside an iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

```
$('#frame').load(function(){

        setTimeout(function() {
            alert($("#frame a[href=check]").length);

        },2000);       

    });
```

The `alert` shows `0`, but iframe loads correctly and link exists.

Answer (score 3):

To fetch contents of an iframe try

```
$('#frame').load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert($('#frame').contents().find('a[href=check]').length);
    }, 2000);
});
```

[.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

> The .contents() method can also be used to get the content document of
>   an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page.

Comment: now we are get error: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://test.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://site.mobi". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Comment: I don't think load(() works in Chrome.  At least it doesn't work for me.